# Exclude Simulink Function block from code generation

Tags: matlab, function, code-generation, simulink

I want to exclude the Simulink Function block from code generation. This means the Simulink Function blocks are in place during simulation (to keep the DiagnosticMonitorCaller block from the AUTOSAR library happy) but are excluded when Matlab is compiling the model for code generation. The reason for this is that the functions are already there and not generated from Matlab/Simulink.

The work around is to 'comment out' during compiling and building but this is not really user and subversion friendly.

Can I use another block to 'fake' the function in place during simulation or do some settings on the Simulink Function block I didn't find?

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved using the [Environment Controller](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/environmentcontroller.html) block.

Comment: I am familiar with this block but this cannot be used. If you look at the Simulink Function (https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulinkfunction.html?s_tid=doc_ta) you see that there are no inputs and outputs you can control with the suggested Environment Controller. This functions are placed in the top level of the model.